# What does [](int* p){delete p;} mean?

Tags: c++

Could someone help me to understand what

```
[](int* p){delete p;}
```

means?

I found it in the docs. for shared_ptr
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a capture-less [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx) that takes a pointer to an `int` and calls `delete` on it. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293603.aspx) another MSDN link that explains the grammar of lambdas.

Answer (score 6):

This denotes a C++11-style [lambda expression](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) ("lambda function"). It takes a pointer to an integer and `delete`s it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it isn't a closure. A closure implies that it captures the enclosing variables, and that lambda doesn't. But that's hair splitting, +1.

Comment: @BillyONeal Thanks, didn't know that. Fixed. (I'm not a C++ guy, again. Probably I should learn C++ before answering C++ questions, lol.)

Comment: That's not a C++ thing. That's just a plain "lambda calculus" thing. But I digress :)

Comment: @BillyONeal In this case, I should probably learn some more general CS, maths and stuff like that before 1. answering any questions 2. trying to argue against someone splitting hair. :D

Comment: WE ARE C++ PROGRAMMERS. WE -ARE- PENDANTICS! ( :P ) BILL SMASH~

Answer (score 4):

it is similar to

```
void foo(int* p){
   delete p;
}
```

but can be written inline as part of another function (for example to be passed as a callback).

Comment: is it? In boost shared_ptr I can not pass foo as a "deleter", I have to create a class with operator() overloaded. Is it different in C++11?

Comment: yes, as noted above this is new syntax added in C++11. Boost is constrained by the capabilities of existing compilers.

Comment: Wait, what?  &foo isn't a valid deleter in `boost::shared_ptr<int>(new int(7), &foo)`?  The docs for `boost::shared_ptr` imply that the deleter type must be copy constructable (which void(*)(int*) is) and `d(t)` must not throw (also true).  Or does a primitive type not qualify as "being CopyConstructable" in boost's eyes?